# Dispersion graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to draw a dispersion diagram in Excel, but that must be vertical, not horizontal.

I have this table and need to graph the "Weighted" column:

[image: table]

When I try, I get this horizontal graph:

[image: try]

What I need is a vertical graph like this that I can superimpose on my table:

[image: goal]

I need the points on the graph aligned with the numbers on the left so I can produce a result Like this:

[image: example]

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear now. Please explain how the graph should look like and what is the logic behind axis numbers.

Comment: The Y axis appears to be a category list with numerical names.  The X axis is non-linear.  It will be difficult for anybody to answer without more information about the data.

Comment: 1) What is the scale of the X axis (it's non-linear)?  I don't believe you can do that natively in Excel.  Do you need that in your graph or can you use a linear scale?  2) You have some values that appear to be in random (maybe chronological) order, and you're connecting sequential values with a line.  Is this supposed to illustrate some sort of progression over time?

Comment: The values are from a subjective evaluation. importance is evaluated from 1 to 5, impact is from -3 to 3 and Wighted is importance*impact.

this is the graph i obtained [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/31d4sxq6k05wxfx/Obtained.PNG?dl=0) (sorry for the link, can´t put in the question). I need to obtain somethin like this [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/lozj1rvdnulw0t8/try.PNG?dl=0) but my problem is that i can´t put the graphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get something like this:
[image]
you do not need to do pretty much.

As i can see, you allready have the chart.
To line it up, you only need a transparent background:
Rightclick your chart and Format it.
[image][image]
(after the hight is as you wanted it, you can do a solid fill again if you like)

For getting the "Limit"-lines you can use a simple trick. Create a small table like the grey one on the right with one empty row (wherever you want). Add a second graph (should be 2 lines) and then simply format them.
[image]

However, to make excel lining up a chart with your cells is as good impossible.

Hopefully that helped at least a bit.